# Timestamp no C# para persistência no SqlServer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Existe alguma tipagem que já trata isso no C# para realizar persistência no banco SQLServer?

Eu preciso resolver a propriedade CreatedAt e UpdatedAt. Para cada alteração, ser armazenada no banco.

```
public class UserBaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

A assinatura na propriedade resolveria este caso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o tipo `Byte[]`, [seguindo padrão da própria Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations#timestamp).

```
[Timestamp]
public Byte[] CreatedAt { get; set; }
```

Definindo o tipo do seu campo como `Byte[]` e usando o atributo `[Timestamp]` ele será gravado com o [tipo rowversion (timestamp) do SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

> timestamp é o sinônimo do tipo de dados rowversion e está sujeito ao
>   comportamento de sinônimos de tipo de dados. Em instruções DDL, use
>   rowversion em vez de timestamp sempre que possível. Para obter mais
>   informações, consulte Sinônimos de tipo de dados (Transact-SQL).

Atualizando o banco de dados com o parâmetro `-Verbose` você terá o seguinte SQL para gerar a tabela (mudando apenas seu campo `CreatedAt` conforme mostrei acima):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserBaseEntities] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [CreatedAt] rowversion NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedAt] [varbinary](max),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.UserBaseEntities] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
```

Comment: Eu uso tanto para o CreateAt quanto para o UpdateAt, certo?

Comment: Sim @ThiagoCunha, não adicionei por que vc não adicionou o [Timestamp] pra esse campo então não tinha certeza se queria ele também dessa forma.

Comment: Vlw... Obrigado! :)